# How do I use Polymer's ripple-animation on a paper-dialog element?

Tags: animation, polymer, web-component

This is what I have for the `paper-dialog` element:

```
<paper-dialog entry-animation="ripple-animation" exit-animation="slide-right-animation" modal>
...
</paper-dialog>
```

Using the 'non-shared' type of animation (`slide-right-animation`) is not an issue and it works fine, but the 'shared' type of animation does not and produces the following error:

```
ripple-animation: fromPage is undefined!
Couldnt play ( ripple-animation ). TypeError: Cannot read property 'cancel' of null(…)
```

How can I use this animation effect on the `paper-dialog` element?

Thanks.

Comment: i don't think you can run `ripple-animation` from `attributes` as from there you won't be able to give values to properties like `fromPage`, `id`, `gesture` of `ripple-animation`

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was thinking, however I've not done this manually yet/not sure the best way of achieving this? Hoping it's a simple case of passing the animation configuration instead?